# Polymer 3, onfocusout or onblur events

Tags: javascript, polymer

how can I invoke onfocusout or onblur menthods in Polymer 3? on-click event works perfectly when I click on menu button but the on-blur or on-focusout doesn't work? I want the menu to close when someone click outside menu?

```
static get properties() {
    return {
      _openMenu: Boolean
    };
  }

_toggleMenu(){
  this._openMenu= !this._openMenu;
}

_closeMenu(){
   this._openMenu= false;
}
```

My button looks something like this

```
<button on-click="${this._toggleMenu()}" on-blur="${this._closeMenu()}">
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok I fixed my problem like this. Just removed the on-click and on-blur event from my button

```
<button>Click</button>
```

On connectedCallBack() I add eventListener to window object, so I can find out where the click has happened. If the click is inside the menu then I toggle my _openMenu, if the click is outside Menu then I false _openMenu

```
connectedCallback() {
    super.connectedCallback();
    this._boundClickHandler = this._clickHandler.bind(this);
    window.addEventListener('click', this._boundClickHandler);
  }

  disconnectedCallback() {
    super.disconnectedCallback();
    window.removeEventListener('click', this._boundClickHandler);
  }

  _clickHandler(event) {
    let clickedInsideMenu = false;
    event.path.forEach((node) => {
      if (!clickedInsideMenu && node === this) {
        clickedInsideMenu = true;
      }
    });

    if (clickedInsideMenu) {
      this._toggleMenu();
    } else {
      this._openMenu= false;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because `on-blur` and `on-focusout` are not defined yet in Polymer library. You can check the existing support gesture events [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/3.0/docs/devguide/gesture-events).

What you can do is to [add events imperatively](https://www.polymer-project.org/3.0/docs/devguide/events#imperative-listeners) by selecting the menu then add an event to it.

Comment: In my case I have done something like this, but now the menu doesn't open when I click on menu

connectedCallback() {
    super.connectedCallback();
    this._boundClickHandler = this._clickHandler.bind(this);
    window.addEventListener('click', this._boundClickHandler);
  }

  disconnectedCallback() {
    super.disconnectedCallback();
    window.removeEventListener('click', this._boundClickHandler);
  }

  _clickHandler() {
   
    if (this._openMenu) {
      this._openMenu = false;
    }
  }